# Java if ternary operator and Collections.emptyList()

Tags: java, generics, casting

Could you please explain why with the first return type the code can't be compiled?
The message is : `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<capture#1-of ? extends Object> to List<String>`.

Is there inserted an explicit cast in the second case ?

```
public class GenericsTest {

        private String getString() {
            return null;
        }

        public List<String> method() {
            String someVariable = getString();
            //first return type
            //return someVariable == null ? Collections.emptyList() : Collections.singletonList(someVariable);
            //second return type
            if (someVariable == null) {
                return Collections.emptyList();
            } else {
                return Collections.singletonList(someVariable);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because of type inference rules. I don't know why *exactly* (you should check the JSL, [the ternary operator section](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.25)), but it appears the ternary expression does not infer the type parameter from the return type.

In other words, the type of the ternary expression depends on the types of its operands. But one of the operands has undetermined type parameter (`Collections.emptyList()`). At that point the ternary expression still does not have a type, so it cannot influence the type parameter. There are two types to be inferred - one is the result of the ternary expression, and the other is the type parameter of the `.emptyList()` method.

Use `Collections.<String>emptyList()` to explicitly set the type

Comment: Could you please explain it in more details ? The question wasn't about how to fix it.

Comment: Pretty much what I'd have answered. I'm too lazy to dig into the JLS at the moment, but I can verify that the rules don't *require* (and in fact don't allow) the deep inspection that would be necessary to let this use of the ternary operator compile. The information is all there, so it would certainly be possible, given the correct rules.

Answer (score 1):

The type of the expression `flag ? trueCase : falseCase` is the most common type of the two cases.

In this case the most common type of `Collections.emptyList()` and `Collections.singletonList(someVariable)` is `List<? extends Object>` because it cannot "see in the future" that `Collections.emptyList()` should return `List<String>` in the expression.

---

When you do:

```
return Collections.emptyList();
```

the compiler can be smart and detect the type by the return type and check the correctness (inferred).

Answer (score 0):

Because `Collections.emptyList()` doesn't return `List<String>`. You set explicit the result of the method to `List<String>` and that means that you have to return a such list.

For example

```
return Collection<String>.emptyList();
```

or

```
return new ArrayList<String>();
```

would work fine.

Comment: Not really: `Collections.singletonList("string")` *does* return a `List<String>` and `Collections.emptyList()` *can* return a `List<String>`, depending on the context (as shown by the second `return` in the sample code).

Comment: -1: Factually incorrect.  Collections.emptyList() and Collections.singletonList("string") do in fact return List.  The problem is with type inference of the generic.

Comment: I'm happy to retract the downvote.  I hadn't of course seen your correction.

Comment: Just to note: Tobias wrote `List<String>` from the very beginning, but since it wasn't marked as code the `<String>` part was interpreted as a HTML tag an silently removed. It still wasn't 100% correct, but not as bad as claiming that `Collections.emptyList()` doesn't return `List`.

Comment: Thank you for your correction, next time I'll use the special characters to mark code as such.

Comment: `Collections<String>.emptyList()` doesn't compile. The correct syntax is `Collections.<String>emptyList()`. I just tried it.