# What is wrong here

Tags: java, templates

This looks rather weird to me. Someone can explain?

Note, that the code never use "? extends", only "? super E", but for some peculiar reason compiler
comes up with "? extends".

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class TestClass <E> {

    private Comparator<? super E> compNatural = new Comparator<E>() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public int compare(E lhs, E rhs) {
            return ((Comparable<E>)lhs).compareTo(rhs);
        }
    };

    private Comparator<? super E> comp; 

    public TestClass(Comparator<? super E> comp) {
        // Reports an error:
        // Type mismatch: cannot convert from Comparator<capture#10-of ? extends Object> to Comparator<? super E> 
        this.comp = (comp==null) ? compNatural : comp;

        // The following compiles OK!!!
        if (comp==null) this.comp = compNatural; else this.comp = comp;         
    }


}
```

Comment: This is not a duplication. See comments below

Comment: This problem happens with generics in general so just use the second option that compiles (and probably works)

Answer (score 1):

This relates to ternary operator not able to infer the correct type. Please check this question [Java if ternary operator and Collections.emptyList()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738938/java-if-ternary-operator-and-collections-emptylist)

Comment: This should be a comment using the link as duplicate.

Comment: I am aware of that, but it looks like this case is different. That thread had List<Object> vs List<String>. Here we have exactly same type: Comparator<? super E>. Please, correct me, if I am wrong.