# Getting error on passing Collections.emptyMap as an argument

Tags: java, generics, collections

I don't understand why I am getting the error on passing the `Collections.emptyMap()` as an argument while assigning `Collections.emptyMap()` to an map reference does not provide error, below is the code sample I tried, I am using JDK1.7

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution sol = new Solution();
        Map<String, String> map = Collections.emptyMap(); //There is no compile time error on this.
        sol.calculateValue(Collections.emptyMap()); //Getting compile time error on this
    }

    //what is the difference in passing Collections.emptyMap() as a parameter
    public void calculateValue(Map<String, String> pMap) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I seem to recall that the Java 1.7, the generic type inference in certain circumstances had issues. A similar problem with using it in something like `return (x != null ? x : Collections.emptyMap())` would also fail to compile.

Comment: I think some information is seen [in this answer about Collections.emptyList()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738938/java-if-ternary-operator-and-collections-emptylist)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're using JDK 1.7, you are not able to benefit from the improved type inference in JDK 8 and above.  It would be best to update the version of Java that you're compiling with.  If that's not an option, then you must explicitly pass the arguments of the `Map` to the function when passing `Collections#emptyMap` as an argument:

```
calculateValue(Collections.<String, String>emptyMap());
```